# Does a deployment to Windows Azure consume available storage transactions?

Tags: azure

I'm using Visual Studio to deploy a web application to an Azure hosted web role and I'm noticing my count of storage transactions creeping up.  My question is does this deployment process count toward my available storage transactions?  If so, is it a single transaction per file deployed?  How is this being calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid VM diagnostics of your application is enabled. Because VM diagnostics collects and transfers logs to Azure Storage, your count of storage transactions will increase. With Windows Azure SDK 1.6, default setting of VM diagnostics is enabled.

Please read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/01/11/with-azure-sdk-1-6-azure-diagnostics-is-enabled-by-default-can-cause-thousands-of-daily-transections-to-azure-storage.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I'll disable that option and see how it goes - thank you, Daichi.

Comment: "I am afraid" ??? Diagnostics is not a bad thing. In fact, it's about the only way you'll be able to collect and aggregate information from running instances. Even if, by default, you're generating 10K transactions daily, that equates to... a penny a day. MSDN subscriptions includes 250K-2M transactions monthly, depending on level. And the free trial includes 50K. So you're talking about maybe 25 cents a month, and that's assuming you make no adjustments to the diagnostics upload frequency during your role's OnStart().

Comment: +1 to David.  It is an extraordinarily bad idea to disable diagnostics and that article should NOT be followed.  If you cannot afford the penny per day extra, then you can at least turn off scheduled transfers and only use on-demand.

Answer (score 1):

If you watch the deployment, Visual Studio uploads the package into blob storage and then will publish it from there to Azure.  That is why your storage count is going up when you deploy.  Diagnostics will also cause your storage transactions to grow.  Another thing that will is if you have IntelliTrace enabled.